# SPFX React npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to work on this react list form [link](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-list-form) , but when i try to do npm install i am getting all these errors below, i checked an article where they mentioned delete package-lock.json file but still no use. Any suggestions or thoughts on this ? Please let me know.

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Desktop\react-list-form\node_modules.staging@uifabric\utilities-fd505e56\lib-amd\initializeDir.js.map'

npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Desktop\react-list-form\node_modules.staging@uifabric\utilities-6f1ef562\lib-amd\IRectangle.js.map'

etc..

Comment: what version of node.js are you on? and npm

Comment: hi denis, node version -  v10.21.0 and npm 6.14.4

Comment: I think you need to be on node version 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following

- Reinstall node 10 LTS. Run installation under local administrator
- Create a new folder on your **C:\ drive**. Don't use your Desktop!
- Navigate to this folder
- run the following commands

```
git clone https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts.git
cd sp-dev-fx-webparts\Samples\react-list-form
npm install
```

I have just run through the whole process and it worked perfectly fine:

[image]

Comment: sorry forgot to reply back, uninstalling and reinstalling worked thanks for your input again.

Comment: @biggie, can you accept the answer, please? if it helped.

Comment: done, my bad i thought i accepted it.